# Finding points in array that is in the specified rectangle( matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix  that is consists of some points of image.look at below

```
Cout=
[215,59;165,126;215,72;236,65;258,60;296,71;296,84;246,77;240,120;228,120;225,74;176,58;178,72];
```

Now I want to find points in rectangle below [x,y,width,height]

```
rec=[105,210,31,31]
```

How should I code it in Matlab?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems none of the `Cout` points are in the rectangle; [check with inpolygon](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html)

Comment: what's Rec coded for? [x y w h] ?

Comment: Yah, i think i should use inpolygon. But i dont know why it is not working for this example

Comment: @m.kavi - regarding your attempts with `inpolygon` - questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include _the desired behavior_, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inpolygon.[https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html]

**HOW IT WORKS:**

in = inpolygon(xq,yq,xv,yv) returns in indicating if the query points specified by xq and yq are inside or on the edge of the polygon area defined by xv and yv.

xq: x-coordinates of query points, specified as a scalar, vector, matrix, or multidimensional array(The size of xq must match the size of yq).

yq: y-coordinates of query points, specified as a scalar, vector, matrix, or multidimensional array.

xv: x-coordinates of polygon vertices, specified as a vector(The size of xv must match the size of yv).

yv: y-coordinates of polygon vertices, specified as a vector.

in: Indicator for the points inside or on the edge of the polygon area, returned as a logical array. in is the same size as xq and yq.

```
% points of image you're searching
% (x,y) are not the coordinates of matrices in MATLAB! And images are 
% matrices. The coordinates of matrices are (row, column) which is NOT (x,y) - it's (y,x). 
yq=Cout(:,1)
xq=Cout(:,2)

xv=[rec(1);rec(1);rec(1)+rec(3);rec(1)+rec(3);rec(1)];
yv=[rec(2);rec(2)+rec(4);rec(2)+rec(4);rec(2);rec(2)];

in = inpolygon(xq,yq,xv,yv)
```

I find 2 points by this way.

Comment: This is a good method, but to make it a good answer you should better describe what is happening in your code. For example, what even is `roi`, what does `inpolygon` do, perhaps a documentation link for further reading...

Comment: In the question the points Cout are defined as (x,y) therefore it should be `xq=Cout(:,1); yq=Cout(:,2)`

Comment: you're right. I should make explanation for why i did this

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need (I think):

```
Cout= [235,65;296,71;296,84;240,120;229,119;224,74;165,126];
Rec=[105,210,31,31];

% set the range of the rectangle in x and y
xr=[Rec(2) (Rec(2)+Rec(4))];
yr=[Rec(1) (Rec(1)+Rec(3))];

% draw the rectangle for ref
rectangle('Position',Rec); hold on

% the next line is what you asked for, checking if points fall in the 
% rectangle I chose here limits with < and >, but you may want <= and >= ...
id = Cout(:,1)<xr(end) & Cout(:,1)>xr(1) & Cout(:,2)<yr(end) & Cout(:,2)>yr(1);

% let's check:
plot(Cout(:,2),Cout(:,1),'x',Cout(id,2),Cout(id,1),'ro')
```

[image]

Comment: Note for future readers that this works because the rectangle is horizontal to the x axis. If the rectangle is rotated (given by 4 points instead of x, y, width, height) then `inpolygon` would be a better solution

Comment: In the question the points `Cout` are defined as `(x,y)` and the rectangle `Rect` as `[x,y,width,height]` therefore it should be `xr=[Rec(1) (Rec(1)+Rec(3))]; yr=[Rec(2) (Rec(2)+Rec(4))];` and `plot(Cout(:,1),Cout(:,2),'x',Cout(id,1),Cout(id,2),'ro') `